# How to Keep Window Focused/More than One Window Focused

Tags: windows, windows-8

Let's say I'm playing a game. Alt-tabbing (losing focus) automatically pauses the game. I want to let the game continue even if I am not focusing on it.

How do I keep focus on a window even if I am focused on another window?

Comment: Depends on the game. If you tell us the game, we might be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Yes it is very dependent on the game, and sometimes trying to bypass it can even flag you as a cheater in some games. I would look into AutoHotKey.

Comment: The behavior you describe is handled by the programs code.  There isn't anything you can do to change that behavior.

Comment: @Lawrence I'm looking for a universal solution, and really tricking a window so that I have more window focused is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

While this might have performance implications that are unacceptable for gaming,
a variation on akira's answer that might work is to run the game program in a virtual machine. 
[This question](https://superuser.com/q/118314/354511) suggests that (at least on *nix hosts) VirtualBox does not tell the guest system if it loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

If the game (or any other program) decides to pause when the focus shifts to another program than you have to live with that. The Window Manager creates a message which tells the window that has now lost the focus (mouse or keyboard focus) about that fact by using events / messages and then the application acts on that. Eg, a browser might decide to stop playing kittens on youtube when you switch over to your Excel spreadsheet at work. Or not.

Comment: In theory, it would be possible for a utility to co-opt some of the window manager's functionality and convince two programs that they were both in focus.  I don't know whether anything like that exists, though.

Comment: it makes not sense to give all programs "focus" because that neglects the meaning of "focus". what the programm does when it loses it focus is upon the program: you may not like it but that is the way it works.

Comment: You cannot actually *give* two programs focus, but you could *trick* a program that is not in focus into thinking it is, and that might be useful.  This is in a similar space to things like browser automation software.  There is no technical barrier to doing this.

Comment: @dan1111 I think you put it best, that was exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: @dan1111: since everything is computed it is indeed possible in theory. because one can change the computation. feel free to answer the solution / how to change that computation in an answer.

Comment: I need to trick a window into thinking it is in focus, too!  (It's Milkdrop.)

Answer (score 1):

While not always available, most modern games have a 'Fullscreen (borderless)' video setting that *may* alleviate this issue you are experiencing with alt-tab.